# Написание функции для открытия и закрытия popup-ов

Tags: javascript, функции, frontend, popup

Пожалуйста, подскажите как сделать так, чтоб это все заработало.

```js
function popupFunc(e) {
  let idPop = this.dataset.forPopupTarget; /*Тут все ок, получаем стоку с id нужного блока*/
  let modal = document.getElementById('"+idPop+"'); /*А тут всегда null, и при использовании `${idPop}`, и при различных способах обратиться к элементу DOM - querySelector(div[id="`${idPop}`"]) и т.д.*/
  let closeBtn = document.modal.querySelector('.popup-close');

  modal.classList.add('show');
  closeBtn.onclick = function() {
    modal.classList.remove('show');
  };
}
let topBtn = document.querySelector('.top-btn');
topBtn.addEventListener('click', popupFunc);
```

```css
.popup {
  display: none;
  /*другие стили*/
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!--Есть сайт, на котором много popup-ов -->

<div class="popup" id="recallForm">
  <div class="popup-dialog">
    <div class="popup-content">
      <button class="popup-close">&times;</button> ....Контент.....
    </div>
    <!-- /.popup-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.popup-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.popup -->
<div class="popup" data-popap-target="recallForm" id="calcForm">
  <div class="popup-dialog">
    <div class="popup-content">
      <button class="popup-close">&times;</button> ....Контент.....
    </div>
    <!-- /.popup-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.popup-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.popup -->
<!--И кнопки для их вызова-->
<button class="btn top-btn popup-btn" data-for-popup-target="recallForm"> Получить консультацию </button>
<button class="btn calc-btn popup-btn" data-for-popup-target="calcForm">Узнать стоимость</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот слегка подправил Ваш код, чаще смотрите в отладчик...

```js
function popupFunc (e) {
  let idPop = this.dataset.forPopupTarget; 
  let modal = document.getElementById(idPop); 
  let closeBtn = modal.querySelector('.popup-close');
  
  modal.classList.add('show');
  closeBtn.onclick = function() {
    modal.classList.remove('show');
  };
}


[...document.querySelectorAll('.btn')]
  .forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', popupFunc));
```

```css
.popup {display: none; /*другие стили*/}
.show {display: block;}
```

```html
<!--Есть сайт, на котором много popup-ов -->

<div class="popup" id="recallForm">
 <div class="popup-dialog">
  <div class="popup-content">
   <button class="popup-close">&times;</button>   
   ....Контент.....
  </div><!-- /.popup-content -->
 </div><!-- /.popup-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.popup -->

<div class="popup" data-popap-target="recallForm" id="calcForm">
 <div class="popup-dialog">
  <div class="popup-content">
   <button class="popup-close">&times;</button>   
   ....Контент.....
  </div><!-- /.popup-content -->
 </div><!-- /.popup-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.popup -->


<!--И кнопки для их вызова-->
  <button class="btn top-btn popup-btn" data-for-popup-target = "recallForm"> Получить консультацию </button>

  <button class="btn calc-btn popup-btn" data-for-popup-target="calcForm">Узнать стоимость</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Вы очень помогли.